# How to make specific pages of a pdf file not load?

Tags: pdf

I want to create a pdf file where specific pages fail to load. It must look like a file error, and the remaining pages must be viewable.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Put a number of invalid instructions into the page content streams in question.

Comment: @mkl Any specific instructions on how to do this or some online resource you can link to? Thanks!

Comment: *"Any specific instructions on how to do this or some online resource you can link to?"* - First of all, how an error is processed, is implementation dependent. It can differ for different PDF processors, even for different versions of the same processor. To achieve "It must look like a file error, and the remaining pages must be viewable," therefore, you'll have to apply trial and error; also you have to be aware that the behavior may change in the next update of the PDF viewer. Also for specific instructions we need to know your tool chain. Which PDF library do you want to use?

Comment: @mkl I don't know what content streams are or how to edit them. Do you have any recommended reading to learn how to do this? I need to do it for several PDF files.

Comment: @mkl Ideally I'd like it to be effective for the main PDF viewers (Acrobat and Edge).

Comment: Ok, so what's your tool chain? Which PDF library for which programming language do you use to manipulate PDFs and want to use for the task at hand?

Comment: @mkl What do you recommend? I'm not familiar with this at all so I need to learn from the basics.

Comment: On one hand software recommendations are off-topic o stack overflow; in the stack exchange context [softwarerecs.se] would be more appropriate. On the other hand you should first become somewhat familiar with the PDF format, e.g. by studying the specification. You can find a copy of the older version ISO 32000-1 at https://Adobe.com/go/pdfreference (To get _arbitrary_ errors it suffices to randomly change some bytes here or there in a PDF. But to get _specific_ errors you should have a basic understanding of what you're doing.)